# read input from command line store it into a 2d array, not as as string input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:                  
    a= f.readlines()    #reads the file's lines
    a = [x.strip() for x in a] #ignores the newline char
print (a)
```

With this function, when I print the array, I have as an output this:

```
['+X..XX....-', '.X..X..X-..', '.X.........', '...XX......', 'XXX.+X.....', '..X.....XXX', '...XXX..X-.', '.-.....X...']
```

How can I convert the above function so as it returns

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

something like this, an array of elements instead an array of strings

Comment: please share 4 lines of your real file. formatted as code. it is not really clear if you got lots of X in your file, if it only contains 0 or what kind of format the numbers have - nor is it clear how the numbers are separated from each other.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what the relationship is between your current output and your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In[3]: with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  ...:     result = [list(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
  ...: 
In[4]: result
Out[4]: 
[['+', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '-'],
 ['.', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', '-', '.', '.'],
 ['.', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['X', 'X', 'X', '.', '+', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', '-', '.'],
 ['.', '-', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', '.']]
```